# Do the functions with infinitely many zeros form a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, contest-math

> Denote by $E$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Rigorously justifying your answer in each case, indicate whether the following subsets of $E$ are vector subspaces of $E$.
>
> $$F=\{f \in E \text{ such that } : f(x) \text{ is zero for infinitely many values of} x\}$$

A is Vector subspace of E if and only if :

- $A\neq \emptyset$
- if $f,g \in A$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(af+bg )\in A $

Indeed

- Since $f=0$ is always $\in A$ then $A\neq \emptyset$
- let  $f,g \in A$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $(af+bg )\in A $

The problem i can't  rigorously justify that

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Can you specify what you mean? I understand that $R$ is a field, and that $E$ is an $R$-vector space consisting of (some) linear mappings $f$. What isn't clear is what the domain and target sets of the maps $f$ is.

Comment: This is took it  from  mathematics contest

Comment: I think it would be okay to post it in the original language below the English.

Comment: Translation: Denote by $E$ the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of all mappings from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Rigorously justifying your answer in each case, indicate whether the following subsets of $E$ are vector subspaces of $E$. $F=\{f \in E \ \text{such that: $f(x)$ is zero for infinitely many values of $x$}\}$.

Comment: Thanks and i hope this is not from google

Comment: No, I translated it. Seeing the French cleared up some uncertainties for me. I think it might be okay to ask your questions in French as well as English. The answer is that $F$ is *not* a subspace: if $f$ and $g$ are both zero for infinitely many values of $x$, it doesn't follow that the same is true for $f+g$. The key insight is that the values of $x$ where $f$ and $g$ are zero need not be the same. To prove that $F$ is not a subspace, however, you'll need to provide a counterexample by exhibiting functions $f,g \in F$ such that $f+g \not\in F$.

Comment: Thanks but math http://math.stackexchange.com/ is english platform

Comment: I don't know. I think this is something to ask more experienced participants. Personally, I had a much easier time understanding the question in French, and I don't see why the website would want to prevent that from happening. Other people were able to read the translation.

Comment: Could you put ur note about question as answer to vote up i like it  That's nice answer

Comment: Educ, here's the answer about posting in another language: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/4384#4384

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your very useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The answer is that F is not a subspace: if $f$ and $g$ are both zero for infinitely many values of $x$, it doesn't follow that the same is true for $f+g$. The key insight is that the values of $x$ where $f$ and $g$ are zero need not be the same. To prove that $F$ is not a subspace, however, you'll need to provide a counterexample by exhibiting functions $f,g \in F$ such that $f+g \not\in F$.

Answer (score 2):

So $E$ is the vector space of all maps from an $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Hint 1

> Consider the map $f$ that takes value $0$ on $\mathbb{Q}$, and $1$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$.

Hint 2

> Consider the map $g$  that takes value $0$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$, and $1$ on $\mathbb{Q}$.

Hint3

> Consider $f + g$.

Comment: $f+g=1$ then $f+g \notin F$

Comment: @Educ, precisely!

Comment: i'm just want to say that  as $f+g \notin F$ then F isn't subspace of E